# Changing height of stack through code and then resetting it in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a stackview whose height is 250. I want to program:

1. When the button is tapped, the stack should go to the top of screen.
2. Then after a few seconds it should go back to its height of 250, which Will be done via dispatchque.main.asynafter

How can I get it to go to the top of the screen & then reset it to its original height?
[The stack I want to go upto the top of the superview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsPmj.png)

Comment: You need to be clear. Do you want to change y constraint position of stackView, and reset it back after sometime or change the height constraint of stack from 250 to something else, and then reset it back?

Comment: height of 250 to height of superview aka the screen then reset it back to 250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure your `stackViewHeightConstraint` has a priority of `999`.
2. Create another constraint like `stackView.topAnchor equalTo superview.topAnchor` (DO NOT ACTIVATE IT).
3. When you hit the button for going to *Expanded* state,
   **activate** this `top-to-top` constraint.
4. When you want to go back to *Normal* state, **deactivate** this `top-to-top` constraint.

#### UPDATE

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var stackView: UIStackView!

    // Assumes that stackView is added as a subview in self.view
    private lazy var topToTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor)
    }()

    @IBAction func expand() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topToTopConstraint])
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.topToTopConstraint])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to do this but I am having difficulty understanding making the point 2 and hence cant get it to work. I am new to swift, can I see some code please?

Comment: See the **UPDATE**.

Comment: before button press

we see that there is white space above stack
and the stacks botton is aligned to the bottom of the superView and top is 'free' after button press

we see that there is white space below stack
and the stacks botton is aligned to the top of the superView and bottom is 'free'

I wanted to have the feature of bottom stays where it is and the stop, which was free joins to the top of the superview, i.e. the views height expands. Is this possible?

Thanks and regards,
Sherry

Comment: Did you make sure the height constraint for stackView is still there constant=250, priority=999? That's point number 1 and it has to exist in parallel to this additional constraint that I mentioned in point number 2.

Comment: Alright, Code is working correctly, I made a new project because the old one had issues even though the constraints were the same as you specified. Once that was done, everything worked liked intended. Thankyou so much for helping me and coding also. God bless ❤